# Using select() to receive from multiple peers using UDP sockets while taking user input from STDIN

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I am implementing a program that runs in multiple servers, exchanging some information through `UDP` socket.

It should also take user commands by listening to `STDIN` and send data to other servers over `UDP` when requested by the user.

The pseudocode is:

```
while(1)
    //reset the timeout value

    while(1)
        int sel = select(fdmax+1, &select_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

        if (sel == -1) {exit(1);} //error
        else if (sel == 0) //timeout
            handle timeout event
            break;

        else
            if stdin
                take user command
            if UDP socket
                recvfrom() messages from other servers, check its IP & port
                to see who sent message within time interval
```

I am having trouble in `else` part.

I have written a similar program with `TCP` sockets, and what it did was iterate through the set of file descriptor with `select()` and if the file descriptor equals `STDIN`, then serve the user command, and if it equals the listener, handle a new connection, and else, receive TCP messages.

UDP is connectionless, so I guess there is no need to handle a new connection.

It seems like I don't even need to maintain a number of sockets to communicate with multiple sockets. Is it correct?

If so, do I only need to create and bind one socket for communication, and run through `STDIN` and that socket, and check for user command and message?

Using pseudocode,

```
FD_SET(STDIN, &master);
FD_SET(socket_fd, &master);


     ...

        else
            for(int i=0; i<socket_fd; ++i)
                if (FD_ISSET(i, &readfds)
                    if (i == STDIN) {handle user commands}
                    else {recvfrom();}
```

Do this look reasonable?

Also, if UDP is connectionless and if I want to send messages to my direct neighbors (what it would be connected peers if this was `TCP`), is storing their IP address and port and sendto() a reasonable way to do it, or is there any better way?

I am not experienced in network programming, and have never used `UDP` socket before, so please verify my deign and correct me for anything wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes. UDP is connectionless, so you can use a single endpoint to communicate with all your clients/peers. You can store their IP address and the source port of their messages (which `recvfrom` gives you) which you can use as the destination IP address and port in a call to `sendto`.